# Creating HTTP4 Endpoint dynamically is correct?

Tags: apache-camel

I am using ProducerTemplate in my project and have some concern regarding performance

```
@Produce
protected ProducerTemplate template;
```

and use as

```
String response = template.requestBody("http4://hostToBeCalled/v1/dogs",MESSAGE_BODY,String.class);
```

In my case, the Endpoint including component(http4) is not known at the time of initialization and I am using producer template to get around it. I see the issue of using template this way because consumer(http4) will be created and destroyed each time requestBody is called.

Does anyone else also see the potential performance issue with it or could suggest the better solution?

Comment: Can you explain your use case more?

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly said, producertemplate may affect performance if it is not correctly handled.

you can use Recipient List which will derive endpoint at run time. You can have some logic to compute your endpoint and assign it to exchange header or property. That header/property can be used by Recipient List to derive endpoint at run time.

If you still stick with ProducerTemplate as your usecase may insisting, -  for better performance, you can inject your producer template instance to a IOC container and let that container to handle its life cycle.

Ref: http://camel.apache.org/why-does-camel-use-too-many-threads-with-producertemplate.html